# How to connect with postgreSQL in aws with vba in excel macros

Tags: excel, vba, windows

So i have vba code and like to connect with postgreSQl on AWS, but i am receiving following error.

**"ODBC: ERROR [08001] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "124.123.122.82", user "dbmasteruser", database "Excel_automation", no encryption**

following is my VBA code.

```
Sub sbADOExample()
    Dim conNew As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cs As String
    cs = "DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64); DSN=PostgreSQL35W; Server=xxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com; Port=5432; Database=Test; UID=dbmasteruser; PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    On Error GoTo conError

    conNew.ConnectionString = cs
    conNew.Open
    If conNew.State = adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox "Connected!"
        Debug.Print "Connected!"
    End If
    Set conNew = Nothing

    pg_db_open = True
    Exit Sub

conError:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Set conNew = Nothing
    pg_db_open = False
End Sub
```

can anyone help me out here also i like to mention that i enabled reference also i added permission on pg_hba.conf but still getting same error

I given permission to  all network to access PostgreSQL inside pg_hba.conf also i tried different drivers to, so i expected it to work fine

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Comment: it doesn't work